# detect pattern in a data.frame column with string_detect too slow in R

Tags: r, stringr

I have a data.frame that have 50,000 rows and 194 columns. In one of the columns named **"Gene"** there are one or multiple entries, always following the same pattern, e.g. "gene1" or "gene1;gene2" or "gene1:gene2:gene3". Then I have a character vector with a regular expression pattern very long e.g **"\bgene1$|\bgene2$|\bgene3$|\bgene4$..."** up to a total of 4,000 patterns, i.e, **4,000 \bgene$**.

I want to find the matches of that pattern in the column `Gene` of my data.frame

Here is an example of the code I am using so far

I cannot output my whole data.frame because it is too long

```
genes <- c("AARS", "AARS1", "SAMD11", "MUTYH", "PEGX", "BRCA1", "APC") # my real number of genes is 3,000

# then I converted the genes' vector to a regexp
genes2 <- paste0("\\b", genes, "\\b")

# then I try the matching
matches <- unique(grep(paste(genes2, collapse = "|"), # tib is my data.frame and Gene the column with the values I want to match
             tib$Gene, value = TRUE, perl = FALSE)) 

# And finally filtering the data.frame
tib2 <- tib %>% dplyr::filter(Gene %in% matches)
```

However, when I use my real data, I get an out of memory error with the grep (setting `perl=FALSE`), so I have tried with `stringr` library but it is too slow to complete the search:

```
test <- str_extract_all(tib$Gene.refGene, paste(genes2,collapse="|"))
test2 <- str_detect((tib$Gene.refGene, paste(genes2,collapse="|"))
```

Both `test` and `test2` are too slow

Any hint on how to update

An example with less rows would be like this, courtesy of @jay.sf

```
d <- structure(list(gene = c("XY42", "SAMD11:XY20:XY29:XY34:XY82:XY88:XY94", 
"XY17:XY23:XY35:XY36:XY8", "MUTYH:XY43:XY62:XY85:XY91:XY92", 
"AARS1:SAMD11:XY100:XY14:XY3:XY51:XY95", "XY2:XY22:XY28:XY69:XY77", 
"AARS1:XY11:XY17:XY62:XY75", "XY25:PEGX:XY47:XY6:XY76:XY84", 
"APC:XY31:XY36:XY48:XY51:XY65", "BRCA1"), x = c(-1.04042150945666, 
-0.4563032693248, -0.267762662765083, 0.758168827559491, -1.89440229591065, 
0.468157951289336, 0.126909754004865, -0.852405668800981, -0.917059466430073, 
-0.475954635098868)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

And the list of genes is fixed `genes <- c("AARS", "AARS1", "SAMD11", "MUTYH", "PEGX", "BRCA1", "APC"`. I want to find the exact match between members of gene list and genes in `Gene` column, i.e, BRCA1 (in gene list) should match only BRCA1 not BRCA11 in `Gene` column in the data.frame.

But bear in  mind that my real gene list has 4,000 genes and my data.frame is composed of 50,000 rows

Comment: A hint: you might check if `stringr::str_detect` works for you. It was suggested in similar questions. Not sure you actually need a regex here. If you really need word boundaries, you will have to build a regex trie from your genes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks, I have tried also with `str_detect` but it is too slow as well, I will update my post

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example of the dataframe. It is not clear *exactly* what you are doing (i.e., do you want matches in the same row as the `gene` column)? A small example with expected output would be helpful.

Comment: @Andrew, thanks, yep I will post the example of jay.sf because he recapitulates my idea

Comment: If the list of genes is static, please add it to the question, I will then be able to provide the faster pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I have updated with an example

Comment: Yeah, but there is not full list of genes, as far as I see, so I can't help. Exactly, share the list of 4K genes, else, I can't help.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, `genes` should be the gene list (now in the post), or do you refer to the genes in the `Gene` column? Thanks a lot

Comment: You build a regex out of the genes, right? I need all those, as in `genes <- c("AARS", "AARS1", "SAMD11", "MUTYH", "PEGX", "BRCA1", "APC")`, but all of them.

Comment: @user2380782 What's wrong with my edited answer?

Comment: @jay.sf, sorry it didn't show up until I have refreshed the browser. I will try it now!!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I could send you a link with the real data, both the gene list and the data.frame, my real number of genes in the gene list could be 7000

Comment: Ok, I see that your input is well-structured (separated with `:` only) so probably you do not need the regex at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your input and output. But assuming data like this,

```
d
#                                     gene          x
# 1                                   XY42 -1.0404215
# 2   SAMD11:XY20:XY29:XY34:XY82:XY88:XY94 -0.4563033
# 3                XY17:XY23:XY35:XY36:XY8 -0.2677627
# 4         MUTYH:XY43:XY62:XY85:XY91:XY92  0.7581688
# 5  AARS1:SAMD11:XY100:XY14:XY3:XY51:XY95 -1.8944023
# 6                XY2:XY22:XY28:XY69:XY77  0.4681580
# 7              AARS1:XY11:XY17:XY62:XY75  0.1269098
# 8           XY25:XY46:XY47:XY6:XY76:XY84 -0.8524057
# 9          XY22:XY31:XY36:XY48:XY51:XY65 -0.9170595
# 10                                  XY36 -0.4759546
```

you could split the genes at `:` using `strsplit` and, first, `match` them with your `genes` vector.

```
## all genes from d
d.genes.0 <- sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(d$gene, "\\:"))))
## genes from d existing in `genes` vector `as.numeric`.
d.genes.1 <- as.numeric(na.omit(match(genes, d.genes.0)))
```

Then second, we convert the splitted genes (as above) to `factor`s and use `d.genes.0` as the factor levels; exploiting numerical conversion of `factors` we finally match on numbers rather than on strings.

```
rw <- sapply(strsplit(d$gene, "\\:"), function(x) 
  any(d.genes.1 %in% as.numeric(factor(x, levels=d.genes.0))))
d[rw, ]
#                                    gene          x
# 2  SAMD11:XY20:XY29:XY34:XY82:XY88:XY94 -0.4563033
# 4        MUTYH:XY43:XY62:XY85:XY91:XY92  0.7581688
# 5 AARS1:SAMD11:XY100:XY14:XY3:XY51:XY95 -1.8944023
# 7             AARS1:XY11:XY17:XY62:XY75  0.1269098
```

Tested with > 4k genes and 50k rows, should work.

---

*Data:*

```
d <- structure(list(gene = c("XY42", "SAMD11:XY20:XY29:XY34:XY82:XY88:XY94", 
"XY17:XY23:XY35:XY36:XY8", "MUTYH:XY43:XY62:XY85:XY91:XY92", 
"AARS1:SAMD11:XY100:XY14:XY3:XY51:XY95", "XY2:XY22:XY28:XY69:XY77", 
"AARS1:XY11:XY17:XY62:XY75", "XY25:XY46:XY47:XY6:XY76:XY84", 
"XY22:XY31:XY36:XY48:XY51:XY65", "XY36"), x = c(-1.04042150945666, 
-0.4563032693248, -0.267762662765083, 0.758168827559491, -1.89440229591065, 
0.468157951289336, 0.126909754004865, -0.852405668800981, -0.917059466430073, 
-0.475954635098868)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Thanks @jay.sf, but the problem is that with my genes are 4,000 and when I use grep it complains about "pattern to long" if perl=T or Out of memory if perl=F

Comment: @user2380782 I understand. Are the gene sequences ordered or unordered? E.g. is `4, 2, 3, 5, 1` possible or just `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`?

Comment: it worked, a quick question, the match is only exact right? For example if a gene in the gene list is named `AAS` and in the gene column is `AAS1` it won't match, won't it?

Comment: @user2380782 Both, the genes in the data frame as well as the genes in the vector are splitted into unique values and being matched. So it's actually a matching of factor levels rather than string matching which would exceed memory limits. Hence only unique values are matched.

Comment: excellent. It still takes time but it is something I need to live with. Thanks!!!